# Splitting a string with quotation marks into an array

Tags: python

I am trying to split a string by quotation marks.

Input:

```
"red1-100, red2-150" "blue1-80, blue2-50, blue3-135" "green1-280, green2-350, green3-635"
```

Output:

```
[["red1-100", "red2-150"], ["blue1-80", "blue2-50", "blue3-135"], ["green1-280", "green2-350", "green3-635"]]
```

Comment: Do you mean split by "`"`" and then by "`, `"?

Comment: I'm trying to group every quotation mark then split the string inside the question mark into their own element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to group up the quoted sections & then split on the commas:

```
import re

s = '"red1-100, red2-150" "blue1-80, blue2-50, blue3-135" "green1-280, green2-350, green3-635"'
res = [m.split(', ') for m in re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', s)]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
inpt = '"red1-100, red2-150" "blue1-80, blue2-50, blue3-135" "green1-280, green2-350, green3-635"'
res = [s.strip('"').split(', ') for s in inpt.split('" "')]

print(res)
# [['red1-100', 'red2-150'], ['blue1-80', 'blue2-50', 'blue3-135'], ['green1-280', 'green2-350', 'green3-635']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first split with `" "`, then loop through every element, then replace `"` with nothing, then you can split that string with `,`

```
yourinput = input()
yourinput = yourinput.split("\" \"")
for i in range(len(yourinput)):
    yourinput[i] = yourinput[i].replace('"', '')
    yourinput[i] = yourinput[i].split(", ")
print(yourinput)
```